# homebrew install error: `livecheck' for Formulary::FormulaNamespace0687b9ea3596758a5cc31a58c3aca98d::Rpm:Class

Tags: homebrew

I am getting an error on trying to install a pkg in brew on mac os mojave:

```
$ brew install --debug aquasecurity/trivy/trivy

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::TapLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/aquasecurity/homebrew-trivy/trivy.rb
==> Installing trivy from aquasecurity/trivy
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/rpm.rb
Error: rpm: undefined method `livecheck' for Formulary::FormulaNamespace0687b9ea3596758a5cc31a58c3aca98d::Rpm:Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
$ brew update-reset && brew update
```

and then retried my command successfully.